# what this line means?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, atlassprites

i found this line in the `init` method from an open source project :

```
AtlasSpriteManager *spriteManager =
    (AtlasSpriteManager*)[self getChildByTag:kSpriteManager];
```

and `kSpriteManager = 0;`

then `spriteManager` used for this purpose

```
     AtlasSprite *bird = [AtlasSprite spriteWithRect:
                         CGRectMake(608,16,44,32) spriteManager:spriteManager];
    [spriteManager addChild:bird z:4 tag:kBird];
```

any idea will be great thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the first line:

```
AtlasSpriteManager *spriteManager = 
    (AtlasSpriteManager*)[self getChildByTag:kSpriteManager];
```

This means that there is a method called `-getChildByTag:` which returns a generic child object. Since the returned object is generic (no specific type) it must be cast to the appropriate type before it can be used. I would guess that the method definition looks something like this:

```
- (id)getChildByTag:(NSInteger)tag;
```

Internally, the class would contain an array of generic child objects, and a specific child can be retrieved by calling `getChildByTag:` with the appropriate tag.

In this case, the programmer knew that the child with tag 0 is an `AtlasSpriteManager`, so they simply cast to that type and then used the `spriteManager` as they normally would.

Comment: this is the method '-(CocosNode*) getChildByTag:(int) aTag
{
 NSAssert( aTag != kCocosNodeTagInvalid, @"Invalid tag");
 
 for( CocosNode *node in children ) {
  if( node.tag == aTag )
   return node;
 }
 // not found
 return nil;
}'

Comment: That makes sense. `AtlasSpriteManager` will be derived from `CocosNode`.